# How to use wp_send_json() and output the value with ajax?

Tags: php, plugin-development, ajax, javascript

Hello Wordpress Developers.

I create my own plugins, and I'm stuck about how to call php functions inside class, into javascript ajax functions.

For example we have button with ID name clickme:

```
<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
```

And then I make a class with functions, example like this:

```
<?php
class myFunctions{
function a(){
$test = "Hello World from wp_send_json()";
wp_send_json($test);
}

}
?>
```

and then I want to output the test variable, using ajax. Example like this:

```
import $ from "jquery";

class trigger{
constructor(){

this.button = $("#clickme");
this.events();

}
events(){
  this.button.on("click", this.buttonHandler.bind(this));

}

buttonHandler(){

$.ajax({
//how to call the Hello World from wp_send_json()?

success: response => {
//if success, alert the "Hello World from wp_send_json";
alert();

}

});


}


}
```

I'm stuck, and I hope I get the help to solve it. Thank you in advance, wordpress Developers!

Comment: Have you tried just logging the value of `response` to see what it is?

Comment: I'm not seeing any AJAX PHP code, there's a class but I see no REST API registration calls or Admin AJAX handler registration. There's also a complete absence of code indenting that makes it difficult to read

Comment: Take a read through the "AJAX"/"Server Side PHP and Enqueuing" pages in the [Plugin Developer Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow below steps:

HTMl Code:

```
<button id="clickMe" data-nonce="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_create_nonce( 'my-nonce' ) ); ?>">Click Me</button>
```

PHP Code: here you need to use [`wp_ajax`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action/) hook.

```
class myFunctions{

    public function __construct(){
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_clickme', [$this, 'ajax_callback']); // for logged in user only
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_clickme', [$this, 'ajax_callback']); // for non logged user only
    }

    public function ajax_callback() {
        $test = "Hello World from wp_send_json()";
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'my-nonce' ) ) {
          wp_send_json_error( 'Sorry, your nonce did not verify.' );
          exit;
        } else {
          wp_send_json($test);
        }
    }
}

$run = new myFunctions();
```

JS Code: for your example, you can ignore `nonce, name`

```
import $ from "jquery";

class trigger {
    constructor() {
        this.button = $("#clickme");
        this.events();
    }

    events() {
        this.button.on("click", this.buttonHandler.bind(this));
    }

    buttonHandler() {
        let ajax_url = "http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
        $.ajax({
            type: "post", // request type get, post
            url: ajax_url, // this sould be http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php url
            data: {
                action: "clickme", // wp_ajax_$action or wp_ajax_nopriv_$action - Important
                nonce: $(this).data('nonce'), // must pass wp nonce and verify to protect CSRF - Very Important for Security
                name: "Razon", // your data, you can pass your own data like this - Optional
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope that help :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's work! I'm curious about the nonce, can you give me a link for me to practice?

Comment: I edit my answer and give an example of how to send and verify nonce.
Create nonce as button data attribute <button id="clickMe" data-nonce="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_create_nonce( 'my-nonce' ) ); ?>">Click Me</button>

Pass nonce when ajax calls and verify it on ajax_callback() method.

Hope this help :)